# I have been using negative margin and positive padding instead calc(), but some issues remain

Tags: html, css

My code is as follows:

**HTML:**

```
<div id="box">
    <div id="left">Left</div>
    <div id="right">Right</div>
</div>
```

**CSS:**

```
html, body {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
#box {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    margin-bottom: -50px;
    padding-bottom: 50px;
    -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    background: red;
}
#box > #left {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    margin-right: -210px;
    padding-right: 210px;
    -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    display: inline-block;
    background: yellow;
    /*overflow-y: scroll;*/
}
#box > #right {
    width: 200px;
    height: 100%;
    display: inline-block;
    /*float: right;*/
    background: green;
    /*overflow-y: scroll;*/
}
```

As you can see from [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/umGbn/), There are 3 comments(`/* ... */`) in the CSS source. One is related to position `#right`, and others are associated with the presence of scroll bars. Looking at the result screen... You can see the long yellow side on the right of `#right`.

I want to remove this(the yellow side) by using `float: right;`(To unwrap `float: right;` comment), but It doesn't work fine... specifically, `#right` box becomes invisible.
What can I do to solve this issue?

And I revert to the original(To re-wrap `float: right;` comment), then I unwrap the `overflow-y: scroll;` comment to enable scroll bars. Likewise, It doesn't work fine... :(
The scroll bars become superimposed on the same space. I want to position the scroll bar of `#left` to the right of `#left` rightly. The remain is like this.
How to solve this issue?

In summary...

Q1. How to position `#right` perfectly?

Q2. How to position the scroll bars of `#left` and `#right` perfectly?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found an answer finally about 3 months later. Hahaha...

Surprisingly, The answer was simple.

1. Add new `#left-wrap` HTML tag on outside of `#left`.
2. Add new `#left-wrap` CSS.
3. Move the all of `#left` CSS to `#left-wrap` except to `background` and `overflow-y`.
4. Add `width: 100%; height: 100%;` in `#left` CSS.
5. Uncomment `overflow-y: scroll;` in `#left` and `#right` and `float: right;` in `#right`.
6. To prevent the disabled in `#right`, Add `position: relative; z-index: 10;`. (You can use any number if large enough.)

You can see the result in **[this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/umGbn/16/)**.

**HTML:**

```
<div id="box">
    <div id="left-wrap">
        <div id="left">
            Left<br />Left<br />Left<br />Left<br />Left<br />Left<br />
            Left<br />Left<br />Left<br />Left<br />Left<br />Left<br />
            Left<br />Left<br />Left<br />Left<br />Left<br />Left<br />
            Left<br />Left<br />Left<br />Left<br />Left<br />Left<br />
            Left<br />Left<br />Left<br />Left<br />Left<br />Left<br />
            Left<br />Left<br />Left<br />Left<br />Left<br />Left<br />
        </div>
    </div>
    <div id="right">
        Right<br />Right<br />Right<br />Right<br />Right<br />Right<br />
        Right<br />Right<br />Right<br />Right<br />Right<br />Right<br />
        Right<br />Right<br />Right<br />Right<br />Right<br />Right<br />
        Right<br />Right<br />Right<br />Right<br />Right<br />Right<br />
        Right<br />Right<br />Right<br />Right<br />Right<br />Right<br />
        Right<br />Right<br />Right<br />Right<br />Right<br />Right<br />
    </div>
</div>
```

**CSS:**

```
html, body {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
#box {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    margin-bottom: -50px;
    padding-bottom: 50px;
    -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    background: red;
}
#box > #left-wrap {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    margin-right: -210px;
    padding-right: 210px;
    -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    display: inline-block;
}
#box > #left-wrap > #left {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    background: yellow;
    overflow-y: scroll;
}
#box > #right {
    width: 200px;
    height: 100%;
    display: inline-block;
    float: right;
    background: green;
    overflow-y: scroll;

    /* To prevent the disabled. */
    position: relative;
    z-index: 10;
}
```

Thanks.